# Unable to install bootstrap in Angular project using ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, angular-bootstrap

I'm having these errors:

> Using package manager: npm √ Found compatible package version:
> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.0.1. √ Package information loaded.
>
> The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.0.1 will be installed and
> executed. Would you like to proceed? Yes npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
> ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving:
> 1-first-project@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/core npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.2" from
> @angular/animations@15.2.2 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
> npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"15.2.2" from
> @angular/platform-browser@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser npm ERR!       peer
> @angular/platform-browser@"15.2.2" from @angular/forms@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!         peer
> @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,
> @angular/router, the root project) npm ERR!     peer
> @angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!       ngx-bootstrap@"^10.2.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!     1 more (the root project) npm ERR!
> peer @angular/core@"15.2.2" from @angular/common@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!     peer
> @angular/common@"15.2.2" from @angular/forms@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!       peer
> @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!         ngx-bootstrap@"^10.2.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!       1 more (the root project) npm
> ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.2.2" from
> @angular/platform-browser@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser npm ERR!       peer
> @angular/platform-browser@"15.2.2" from @angular/forms@15.2.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!         peer
> @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,
> @angular/router, the root project) npm ERR!     4 more
> (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...) npm ERR!   7
> more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could
> not resolve dependency: npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"14.0.1"
> from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:
> @angular/core@15.2.3 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core npm ERR!
> peer @angular/core@"15.2.3" from @angular/forms@15.2.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^15.2.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from
> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.0.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap npm ERR!
> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"14.0.1" from the root project npm ERR! npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
> ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\m4357\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-22T09_51_52_268Z-eresolve-report.txt
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\m4357\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-22T09_51_52_268Z-debug-0.log
> × Packages installation failed, see above.

Comment: Did you look at the debug log referenced in the error message?